# Powershell temporarily change path for session

Tags: command-line, powershell, python, path

I'm writing a powershell script to setup some python environment stuff and execute some code. I ran into an issue early on with [virtualenvwrapper-powershell not installing for python3](https://bitbucket.org/guillermooo/virtualenvwrapper-powershell/issues/5/cant-install-package-with-python3-and-pip) (`virtualenv` installs/works just fine on its own).

I don't need the full functionality of `virtualenvwrapper-powershell`, I know can simulate it just fine by changing which `python` is used when the command `python` (and `pip` etc) is used. If I can change the value of path within the current powershell session or just within the script I'll be able to get by, but I don't want to make changes to the path permanent or system wide. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excerpt from Windows PowerShell help:

```
  To make a persistent change to an environment variable, use System in
  Control Panel (Advanced tab or the Advanced System Settings item) to
  store the change in the registry.

  When you change environment variables in Windows PowerShell, the change
  affects only the current session. This behavior resembles the behavior
  of the Set command in Windows-based environments and the Setenv command
  in UNIX-based environments.
```

For full details, issue the following command:

```
get-help environment -ShowWindow
```